# How to detect whether salesforce lightning app is running on a mobile browser or desktop browser?

Tags: javascript, css, browser, salesforce, ie8-browser-mode

We have salesforce lightning app which runs on both mobile and desktop. Need to write some code only for mobile application. How to detect whether app is running on a mobile browser or desktop browser? 
I used following code but its not working:

```
checkMobileBrowser: function(component){
    if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)){
        return true;        
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The $Browser global value provider returns information about the hardware and operating system of the browser accessing the application.

Returns a FormFactor enum value based on the type of hardware the browser is running on.

DESKTOP for a desktop client
PHONE for a phone including a mobile phone with a browser and a smartphone
TABLET for a tablet client (for which isTablet returns true)

```
Ctrl

({
    checkBrowser: function(component) {
        var device = $A.get("$Browser.formFactor");
        alert("You are using a " + device);
    }
})
Component

<aura:component>
        {!$Browser.isTablet}
        {!$Browser.isPhone}
        {!$Browser.isAndroid}
        {!$Browser.formFactor}
    </aura:component>
```

By using this way you can determine

Resource: http://www.janbask.com/salesforce-lightning

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the `$Browser` global value provider:

```
function checkMobileBrowser(){ 
   return $A.get("$Browser.formFactor") !== "DESKTOP"
}
```

This will ensure that your detection matches what the application uses, if your component is ever embedded in S1 or SFX, and everything will switch on the same logic.

`$Browser` is also available in component markup:

```
<aura:if "{!$Browser.formFactor !== 'DESKTOP'}">
   <component/>
</aura:if>
```

You might want to search the documentation for `$Browser`, because it allows for very granular hardware detection, and there might be something else for your specific use case.

https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/lightning.pdf

Answer (score 0):

you can write JavaScript function for validation of browser's user agent:

```
function detectmob(){ 
    if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)
            || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i)
            || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)
            || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)
            || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)
            || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)
            || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```